# Can we use bootstrap modal backdrop as a standalone component

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

my question is that can i use bootstrap's modal plugin's backdrop as a separate standalone component, if i have to use backdrop for some other purpose.
If possible then how to use it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't use bootstrap backdrop as a standalone component.

I have written the following js function, inherited from bootstrap, for using backdrop.

The function use jquery like bootstrap.

```
    var backdrop = function () {
        var that = this
        var animate = 'fade'
        that.$body = $(document.body)
        that.__TRANSITION_DURATION = 300
        that.__BACKDROP_TRANSITION_DURATION = 150

        this.show = function (callback) {
            var doAnimate = $.support.transition && animate

            that.$backdrop = $(document.createElement('div'))
              .addClass('modal-backdrop ' + animate)
              .appendTo(that.$body)

            if (doAnimate) that.$backdrop[0].offsetWidth // force reflow

            that.$backdrop.addClass('in')

            if (!callback) return

            doAnimate ?
              that.$backdrop
                .one('bsTransitionEnd', callback)
                .emulateTransitionEnd(that.__BACKDROP_TRANSITION_DURATION) :
              callback()
        }

        this.hide = function (callback) {

            if (that.$backdrop) {
                var callbackRemove = function () {
                    that.$backdrop && that.$backdrop.remove()
                    that.$backdrop = null
                    callback && callback()
                }

                $.support.transition ?
                    that.$backdrop
                    .one('bsTransitionEnd', callbackRemove)
                    .emulateTransitionEnd(that.__BACKDROP_TRANSITION_DURATION) :
                    callbackRemove()
            }
        }

        return this
    }
```

and this is the code for using it:

```
      function showBackdrop() {

            var bd = new backdrop()
            bd.show(function () { })
            setTimeout(function () { bd.hide() }, 2000)
        }
```

in both functions show and hide You have a callback for doing custom actions, exactly like bootstrap.

Note. You must set the show callback function for backdrop taking effect. For hide function it's no required.